# Python win32com Outlook Stores not iterable

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

Trying to list all Outllook stores (and finally all e-mails in those stores):

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
stores = outlook.Stores
print(stores.Count)
for store in outlook.Session.Stores:
    print(store.GetRootFolder())
```

While it was still working yesterday I see the following output today:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
10
  File "C:/Users/DJ/PycharmProjects/Mailmagic/outlook_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for store in outlook.Session.Stores:
TypeError: 'Stores' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In between I was running makepy.py. Version: Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

Comment: Should it be `outlook.Stores` or `outlook.Session.Stores`?

Comment: Not sure. Whatever gives me access to all pst files in Outlook. Anyhow: same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally switching from stores to outlook.Folders worked for me. See below.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
for folder in outlook.Folders:
    print(folder.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have imported data file in outlook, and later deleted the file from local directory without close/removing those "outlook data files" from outlook.

i had same problem, once i closed all the "Outlook Data File" it worked for me.
But not sure how to do this programatically.