# Cannot iterate certain collections of Outlook COM objects using win32com

Tags: python, loops, foreach, outlook, win32com

I am seeing a similar issue to this question:

[Python win32com Outlook Stores not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569888/python-win32com-outlook-stores-not-iterable)

I can write this in VBA (having included the reference to the Microsoft Outlook object library):

```
Dim ol As New Outlook.Application

Dim s As Outlook.Namespace

Set s = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim ac As Outlook.Account

For Each ac In s.Accounts
    Debug.Print ac.DisplayName
Next ac
```

And it happily prints out the account name(s).

When I try and port to Python using this code:

```
import win32com.client as wc    

ol = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
ns = ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')

for ac in ns.Accounts:
    print(ac.DisplayName)
```

I get the error message `'Accounts' object is not iterable.`

If instead I write this:

```
for n in range(1,ns.Accounts.Count +1):
    print(ns.Accounts.Item(n).DisplayName)
```

the code runs as expected.

Further, if I change the object creation line to:

```
ol = wc.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
```

and delete the `gen_py` files (and so forcing late binding), the iteration also works.

So, it seems to be an issue with the generated gen_py wrapper not providing the "iterability" of the Accounts object.

I also find this with the `Stores` collection, but not with the `Folders` collection (as per the other question above).

Comment: Use the `for` loop instead.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Well, that would be the practical solution. However I would still like to understand why apparently VBA can achieve early binding of the iterable collection but win32com cannot (though late binding does work). Is it a deficiency of win32com or an artefact of the type library?

Comment: Try to check the source code of the win32com library.

Comment: It seems that with the current Outlook Type Library, the Accounts and Stores collections aren't working properly with the Python implicit `iter()` and `win32com`. One workaround is to invoke the `__iter__()` function explicitly for the collections. eg `for ac in ns.Accounts.__iter__():`