# Python 'outlook.Session.Accounts' can't iterate, new bug?

Tags: python, foreach, outlook, win32com, office-automation

Hi I am using win32 Outlook via python to send email from a specific mailbox that is already connected from my Outlook app.
Code is straightforward. I was able to run successfully last week.

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
for c in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    mail.To = '123@gmail.com'
```

But today it failed with '*Accounts' object is not iterable*'

[image: error]

I only installed xlrd last week.

Comment: I had a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73673465/cannot-iterate-certain-collections-of-outlook-com-objects-using-win32com The quick answer is to use the `Count()` method of `Accounts` and use that in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys for the solution hint and explanation, this is exactly how the problem is solved.

```
for c in range(1, outlook.Session.Accounts.Count+1):
    if (outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(c).DisplayName) == '123@gmail.com':
        mailfrom = (outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(c))
        #print(outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(c).DisplayName)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird problem of using python with win32com library. Instead of iterating over objects in the collection you need to use the [Accounts.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.accounts.item) method in the loop which iterates over numbers of accounts from 1 to `Accounts.Count`.

Comment: Fwiw, I'm still waiting for an answer from the `win32com` team on this. For some Office collections the iteration works fine, but for others it only works with late-binding. My beef with win32com is that it can switch from late-binding (ie working fine) to early-binding (not working) without the user making any changes to their code (as with the OP). win32com uses a file-based cache to generate early-binding wrappers, so one program can create a cache without another program being aware. There are numerous SO questions which are caused by this 'feature'.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to update your original post then.