# How to iterate through multiple outlook accounts using win32com.client

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I have a requirement where in i need to handle 3 outlook accounts set in one profile. The scenario is similar for all 3 accounts, i just need to run through the scenario in 3 accounts one by one. Use case is as follows

Account_One has a folder in it : Folder_One. I will receive a mail in this folder with unique id in subject. I need to fetch data the To, Cc, Bcc and Comments data from an excel workbook. Update the mail with this info and move it to the drafts folder.
Account_Two has a folder named Folder_Two and similarly Folder_Three for Account_Three.

I have handled the scenario for the single account.
I am trying to iterate through a list of COM objects of account and folder name in a for loop to do this same process for different accounts but get a error that COM object is not iterable.
Please suggest a way to overcome this scenario or how can I handle this.

Here is the code which I am trying

```
import win32com.client as client
From openpyxl import load_workbook

outlook = client.Dispatch(‘Outlook.Application’)
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace(‘MAPI’)

accounts = [acc for acc in namespace.Folders if ‘account1@xyz.com’ or ‘account2@xyz.com’ == acc.Name
```

this gives me a list of accounts with type <class ‘win32com.client.CDispatch’>

```
for account in accounts:
    root = namespace.Folders[account]
    for folder in root.Folders:
        req_folder = root.Folders[folder]
```

this folder is currently a list of strings of the required folder names… you can suggest how can I get it as a COM Object as well…

Below code is just to manipulate the excel and mail.. which works fine if I use only one account.

I get an error on line
——> root = namespace.Folders[account]
TypeError(“This object does not support enumeration”)

Please suggest a way to work this out

Comment: The Folders collection can be indexed `[]` by number (1-based), or by string. The `account` object is neither of those. Try `root=namespace.Folders[account.Name]` instead. When I run the OP's original code, I get a different error which complains of a `Type mismatch` which is what I would expect. The `This object does not support enumeration` error seems to crop up when using `win32com` with Outlook collections: eg my own question previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73673465/cannot-iterate-certain-collections-of-outlook-com-objects-using-win32com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
root = namespace.Folders[account]
```

with

```
root = namespace.Folders.Item(account)
```