# Win32 not recognising the outlook email in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, outlook, pywin32, win32com

Tried to read the outlook email in jupyter notebook for creating a ML algorithm but the win32 is not recognising my outlook account. It was working fine yesterday but somehow same code not wrking today.

Any suggestions please?

Attached my code below.

```
import win32com #.client
import pyttsx3
#other libraries to be used in this script
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
# mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
# mapi
# for account in outlook.Accounts:
#     print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
# account
# inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
outlook.Accounts
```

The result I'm getting is
[image]

Comment: Where and when do you run the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hit something similar [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73673465/cannot-iterate-certain-collections-of-outlook-com-objects-using-win32com).

EDIT: An update. It seems that the Python `iter(obj)` function implicit in the `for` loop is not necessarily calling `obj.__iter__()` but calls instead `obj.__class__.__iter__(obj)` and this isn't working properly for some reason (I read this in an SO answer that I have lost), so one solution is to call `__iter__()` directly.

eg this works:

```
import win32com.client
ns = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")

accs = ns.Accounts
for ac in accs.__iter__():
    print(ac.DisplayName)
```

//EDIT

The issue seems to be that all of a sudden the Collection objects are not iterable when they should be. For example:

```
import win32com.client
ns = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
accs = ns.Accounts
```

then:

```
accs.Count
```

returns `1` (I have one account)

*But this subsequent code:*

```
for ac in accs:
    print(ac.DisplayName)
```

gives this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [20], line 1
----> 1 for ac in accs:
      2     print(ac.DisplayName)

TypeError: 'Accounts' object is not iterable
```

If you don't use the built-in Python iteration, but instead iterate by (1-based) index:

```
accs = ns.Accounts
for n in range(1,accs.Count+1):
    ac = accs.Item(n)
    print(ac.DisplayName)
```

you get a list of accounts as expected.

I did raise a bug-report for `win32com` [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1943) but I am not sure anything happened. Interestingly I don't get this issue with the Folders collection, eg

```
fldrs = ns.Folders
for f in fldrs:
    print(f.Name)
```

works as expected.

**So the workaround** is to use explicit indexing using the `Item()` method of the collection.

EDIT: You can also try deleting everything in your `%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\gen_py\x.x` folder (where `x.x` is the Python version) and re-trying.

Comment: Thank you for the above suggestion. I tried to read the body/subject of the email but throwing error. ```outbox = nss.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
messages = outbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
print(messages[0].body)``` Getting the error ```com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Array index out of bounds.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

Comment: Nearly all Office collections are 1-based. ie the first item in the collection is index 1, not 0.

Comment: Thank you!, Last one doubt, how can we read the body of the email?? I tried with ```messages[1].body``` but it throws as ```AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._MailItem instance at 0x1904264209888>' object has no attribute 'body'```

Comment: Once you start using the gen_py files you need to get the case correct on the method/property names. The property is `Body` with an uppercase B. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code contains multiple method calls:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

So, I'd recommend splitting them by declaring each method call on a separate line of code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
nameSpaceObj = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Following that way you can find which method exactly gives the error (if any).

Sometimes you need to get the standard folder first (for example, Inbox) to get MAPI subsystems initialized:

```
inbox = nameSpaceObj.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

Another possible cause is already running Outlook instance. In that case you need to try to retrieve the running instance on the system. Use the `GetObject` function instead:

```
outlook = win32com.client.GetObject('outlook.application')
```

You can't run two instances of Outlook at the same time on the computer.

Comment: @eugene_Astafiev, Tried both the ways but none works.  not able to get the accounts itself. But it was working fine yesterday.

Code tired now:
```outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
nameSpaceObj = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = nameSpaceObj.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages```

Comment: And I'm running the anaconda jupyter notebook in my local machine

Comment: Do you have Outlook running in the background? Try to check the list of running processes on the machine.

Comment: @Eugene_Astafiev, yes my outlook is running in the background

Comment: Try using the `win32com.client.GetObject (filename)` function instead.